# ResultSet is not updatable even though its set to CONCUR_UPDATABLE

Tags: java, mysql

Im trying to add a new row to my db with the code below, even though this has been explicitly stated on the code, I still get that error

```
ResultSet rs12 = null;
                        String sql1 = ("Select admin.* From admin");
                        Statement st1 = cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                        rs12 = st1.executeQuery(sql1);
                        if(!rs12.equals(null))
                        {
                            JdbcRowSet regis = new JdbcRowSetImpl(rs12);
                            regis.setConcurrency(java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                            regis.last();
                            int id=Integer.parseInt(regis.getString("id"))+1;
                            regis.moveToInsertRow();
                            regis.updateInt("id", id);
                            regis.updateString("username", adminname);
                            regis.updateString("password", pass);
                            regis.insertRow();
                            regis.moveToCurrentRow();
                            textAdmin.setText("");
                            passwordAdmin.setText("");
                            passwordAdminConfirm.setText("");
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You have Successfully Registered!");

                            log.close();
                            regis.close();
                        }
```

Im getting the error below:
[image]

Comment: You are inserting, not updating, in the insert row. You should be calling `setInt()` etc. in the insert row.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling regis.setType with ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE or ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE